# no data appears in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, flask, dynatable

I have the following script:

```
var dataSet;
d3.json("/TableData", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  dataSet = json;
});

$('#data-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: dataSet
  }
});
```

`/TableData` is a sqlalchemy call to a db which returns:

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "Type": "Turbine", 
  "Seconds": 170, 
}, 
{
  "Type": "Turbine", 
  "Seconds": 75435, 
}]}
```

I don't get any errors with the console but nothing shows up in the `flask` website? if I go to `http://127.0.0.1/TableData` I can see the table data.

Comment: also on the mark as duplicate i didn't know what an asynchronous call was so couldn't find that answer in search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why because `d3.json` function is asynchronous and `dataSet` variable may be set only after the execution of dynatable code.

So try this way.

```
d3.json("/TableData", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  var dataSet = json;
  $('#data-table').dynatable({
    dataset: {
       records: dataSet
    }
  });
});
```

You can confirm this by console logging the `dataSet` variable value from inside the `d3.json` callback function and outside the function.